# Scrapy KeyError while using pipeline

Tags: python, scrapy, keyerror

Can someone explain me why I get this error? I didn't get it. I try to store my extracted data into a database via scrapy pipeline, it worked for another project but now I get the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 588, in _runCallbacks
        current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
      File "/home/Darknet/Darknet/pipelines.py", line 11, in process_item
        length = range(len(item['quantity']))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scrapy/item.py", line 56, in __getitem__
        return self._values[key]
    KeyError: 'quantity'
```

My pipeline:

```
import Darknet
from Darknet.items import DarknetItem
from models import db
from models import BlackMarket


class MysqlPipeline(object):

    def process_item(self, item, spider):

        length = range(len(item['quantity']))
        for x in length:
            record = BlackMarket(product=item['product'][x], quantity=item['quantity'][x], price=item['price'][x])
            db.add(record)
            db.commit()
        return item
```

I use the items in this code snippet:

```
item = DarknetItem()
item['product'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="text oTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
item['price'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="bottom oPrice"]/text()').extract()
item['quantity'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="text oTitle"]/a/text()').extract()
yield item
```

Comment: You have created no field `quantity` in `DarknetItem()`

Comment: What do you mean? In the items.py file quantity is set to a scrapy.Field() so I didn't think thats the issue.

Comment: Add a runnable example that replicates your issue

Comment: I deleted return item in pipeline. That solved the problem.